# How do I make sure that I have deleted/updated my own record in DynamoDB without USER ID in that table

Tags: database, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, modeling

I'm quite new to DynamoDB. So I have a lot of questions about this one.

I made a model relationship like below

**Table Relationship**

- Many `Users` have many Projects
- One Project has many Suites
- Suites has many Cases

*Tables Model*

*Users Table*

```
+-------------+------------+
| UserID (PK) | Attributes |
+-------------+------------+
|     U_01    |     ...    |
+-------------+------------+
|     U_02    |     ...    |
+-------------+------------+
|     U_03    |     ...    |
+-------------+------------+
```

*Projects Table*

```
+-----------+------------+
| ProjectId | Attributes |
+-----------+------------+
|   PJ_01   |     ...    |
+-----------+------------+
|   PJ_02   |     ...    |
+-----------+------------+
|   PJ_03   |     ...    |
+-----------+------------+
```

*UserProject Table*

```
+-------------+----------------+------------+
| UserID (PK) | ProjectID (SK) | Attributes |
+-------------+----------------+------------+
|     U_01    |      PJ_01     |     ...    |
+-------------+----------------+------------+
|     U_02    |      PJ_02     |     ...    |
+-------------+----------------+------------+
|     U_03    |      PJ_01     |     ...    |
+-------------+----------------+------------+
```

*Suites Table*

```
+------------------+----------------+------------+
|   SuiteId (SK)   | ProjectId (PK) | Attributes |
+------------------+----------------+------------+
|  S_01            |      PJ_01     | ...        |
+------------------+----------------+------------+
|  S_02            |      PJ_02     | ...        |
+------------------+----------------+------------+
|  S_03            |      PJ_01     | ...        |
+------------------+----------------+------------+
```

*Cases Table*

```
+-----------------+------------------+------------+
|   CaseId (PK)   |   SuiteId (SK)   | Attributes |
+-----------------+------------------+------------+
|       C_01      |        S_01      | ...        |
+-----------------+------------------+------------+
|       C_02      |        S_01      | ...        |
+-----------------+------------------+------------+
|       C_03      |        S_01      | ...        |
+-----------------+------------------+------------+
```

In order to update or delete a test case (ex: C_01), i gotta make sure that users mustn't delete non-owned items (ex: U_02 will not allow to delete C_01). BTW, I got user id from token after authenticated

I've designed a API Endpoint like below to UPDATE or DELETE data. Could you tell me your best practices in this case. Thanks a lot.

UPDATE: /cases/:id

DELETE: /cases/:id

(I don't make some thing like /projects/:prjId/suites/:sId/case/:cId as Microsoft best practices suggestion in API creation)

Comment: you are trying to model you schema like sql, dynamodb is not a good fit with the above schmea

Comment: @best wishes Do you have any suggestion for above approach

Comment: @best wishes Thanks for your suggestion in cookie approach. What is the best way to model my approach with DynamoDB. If you don’ mind could you please give me some suggestion.

Comment: I am immensely sorry about the cookies comment, my mind was in another thread context, and you got a dirty read :(. 
WRT above suggestion, why not use sql technologies like postgres, mysql?

Comment: My company is using this for all project. So I have no idea. I’m not a fan of NoSQL at all. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days, I rethink the way I approached table for relational model.

With DynamoDB, we have 2 definitions to resolve RDS. 
 - Global Secondary Index (GSI)
 - [Adjacency List](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-adjacency-graphs.html)

And I figure out ["AWS re:Invent 2018: Amazon DynamoDB Deep Dive: Advanced Design Patterns for DynamoDB"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k) Video. Blown my mind.

They suggest that we should use `1 table for 1 application`, `Hierarchical Data Structure as Items`, `pair partition key and sort key to query` and `GSI`.

But I still no clear in my case until @Rick Houlihan [give me an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55753887/4642316).